# Lua text parsing, space handling

Tags: regex, parsing, text, lua

I'm a newbie to Lua. And I want to parse the text like

```
Phase1:A B Phase2:A B Phase3:W O R D Phase4:WORD
```

to

```
Phase1         Phase2      Phase3     Phase4

A              A B         W O R D    WORD
```

I used `string.gmatch(s, "(%w+):(%w+)")`, I can only get

```
Phase1     Phase2     Phase3       Phase4

A          A          W            WORD
```

How can I get missing B, O, R, D back?
Or do I need to write pattern for every phases? How to do that?

Comment: `for k, v in s:gsub('%s*(%w+:)','\0%1'):gmatch'%z(%w+):(%Z*)'`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff's solution works great. But I don't know how to add his suggestion as answer. Could you please explain what's '\0%1' '%z' function? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k, v in s:gsub('%s*(%w+:)','\0%1'):gmatch'%z(%w+):(%Z*)'
```

– @Egor Skriptunoff
This pattern works better.

Comment: I have trouble to parse out decimals while modifying greatwolf's answer. So @Egor Skriptunoff's solution is the only right answer for my quesiton.　Please vote at commment below my question.

Answer (score 4):

The input text in your example doesn't have any clear delimiter between the phrases so parsing it accurately with regex is tricky.

This would be much easier to parse if you add a delimiter symbol like a `,` to separate the phrases.

```
Phrase1:A B, Phrase2:A B, Phrase3:W O R D,Phrase4:WORD
```

You can then parse it with this pattern:

```
s = "Phrase1:A B, Phrase2:A B, Phrase3:W O R D,Phrase4:WORD"

for k, v in s:gmatch "(Phrase%d+):([^,]+)" do
    print(k, v)
end
```

outputs:

```
Phrase1 A B
Phrase2 A B
Phrase3 W O R D
Phrase4 WORD
```

If it's not possible to relax the above constraint, you can try this pattern:

```
  s:gmatch "Phrase%d+:%w[%w ]* "
```

Note there's a caveat with this pattern, the string you're parsing needs to have an extra space at the end or the last phrase won't get parsed.

Comment: Thanks. The text is from machine log. So I cannot add comma to all of them. The true text is even less organized, like --- `aperture:2.8 ProcessSpeed:High throughput BrightLevel:123.12`. I cannot use "Phrase" as identifier. The test name is an single word but the result could be several words.